# How to user Fn::Join in serverless framework YAML?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

I have a Policy in Serverless.yaml file as mentioned bellow.

```
    AppSyncDynamoDBPolicy:
      Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
      Properties:
        Description: 'Managed policy' 
        Path: /appsync/
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: 2012-10-17
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action: 
                - dynamodb:GetItem
                - dynamodb:PutItem
                - dynamodb:DeleteItem
                - dynamodb:UpdateItem
                - dynamodb:Query
                - dynamodb:Scan
                - dynamodb:BatchGetItem
                - dynamodb:BatchWriteItem
              Resource: 
                Fn::Join: 
                  - ""
                  - - Fn::GetAtt: [dslvehicleState, Arn]
                    - "*"
```

when sls deploy is done it throws an error as mentioned bellow.

> An error occurred: AppSyncDynamoDBPolicy - Syntax errors in policy.
>   (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID:
>   166ba0b3-cc67-11e8-8f74-3339d857f829).

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, using the `Ref` method:

```
AppSyncDynamoDBPolicy:
  Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
  Properties:
    Description: 'Managed policy' 
    Path: /appsync/
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: 2012-10-17
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action: 
            - dynamodb:GetItem
            - dynamodb:PutItem
            - dynamodb:DeleteItem
            - dynamodb:UpdateItem
            - dynamodb:Query
            - dynamodb:Scan
            - dynamodb:BatchGetItem
            - dynamodb:BatchWriteItem
          Resource: 
            Fn::Join: 
              - ""
              - - "Ref": "dslvehicleState"
                - "*"
```

Answer (score 1):

After checking and retrying i found that srings should be maked using ''

```
AppSyncDynamoDBPolicy:
  Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
  Properties:
    Description: 'Managed policy' 
    Path: /appsync/
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: '2012-10-17'
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action: 
            - 'dynamodb:GetItem'
            - 'dynamodb:PutItem'
            - 'dynamodb:DeleteItem'
            - 'dynamodb:UpdateItem'
            - 'dynamodb:Query'
            - 'dynamodb:Scan'
            - 'dynamodb:BatchGetItem'
            - 'dynamodb:BatchWriteItem'
          Resource: 
            Fn::Join: 
              - ""
              - - Fn::GetAtt: [dslvehicleState, Arn]
                - "*"
```

After replacing below settings works smoothly

> Version: '2012-10-17'
>   Action: 
>    - 'dynamodb:GetItem'
>    - 'dynamodb:PutItem'
>    - 'dynamodb:DeleteItem'
>    - 'dynamodb:UpdateItem'
>    - 'dynamodb:Query'
>    - 'dynamodb:Scan'
>    - 'dynamodb:BatchGetItem'
>    - 'dynamodb:BatchWriteItem'

Answer (score -1):

```
AppSyncDynamoDBPolicy:
  Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
  Properties:
    Description: 'Managed policy' 
    Path: /appsync/
    PolicyDocument:
      Version: 2012-10-17
      Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action: 
            - dynamodb:GetItem
            - dynamodb:PutItem
            - dynamodb:DeleteItem
            - dynamodb:UpdateItem
            - dynamodb:Query
            - dynamodb:Scan
            - dynamodb:BatchGetItem
            - dynamodb:BatchWriteItem
          Resource: !GetAtt "dslvehicleState.Arn"
```

You can read more about Return Values [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#w2ab1c21c10d385c15).

Comment: I think we cant user !GetAtt in serverless framework. hence this will not resolve the issue. !GetAtt "dslvehicleState.Arn"

Comment: You could replace the resource with;

`!Sub "arn:aws:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:table/${dslvehicleState}"` 

Where "dslvehicleState" = the value given to TableName in your DynamoDB resource.